# What is the software used for drawing like this sketch?

Tags: software-recommendation, diagram, technical-drawing

What is the software used for drawing like this sketch? [image]

Comment: Practically *any* image creation/editing software *could* create that. You'll need to be far more specific.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no way to tell for sure, but I would suggest you use a vector image editor if you want to recreate a diagram like that.

Comment: yes i want to creat a giagram like that , i found ansys or solidwork hard for draw it ,  i search for editor by piking with the mouse  and a simple in using

Comment: To be honest this isnt any easier to draw in solidowrks than illustrator or inkscape. Other alternative is to use TiKZ. Not sure easier is the word i would use.

Answer (score 2):

Ansys SpaceClaim or Solidworks (said in your comment) are intended for making 3D models and  drawings of them. It's expected that they are quite rigid for making easily a replica of your example.

This is a symbolic presentation of a scene and contains what's needed to start to write an explanation of some relations in that scene. You need flexible tools for drawing curves lines and markers (=here points and arrows). In addition you must be able to  name the items by writing the same style names as used in math expressions.

Vector drawing programs would be useful. Just to make replica of your image by drawing it I would use Illustrator or Inkscape. Both need some practicing even to get started. If you have math equations somewhere I would copy the symbolic names from them.

Open Office (freeware) and Microsoft Office have some vector drawing and math equation writing tools which can get close, but for drawing quickly the curves and markers Illustrator and other vector drawing programs are far more felexible.

BTW the next image is drawn in Inkscape.

[image]

It takes about ten minutes if the most basic path drawing tricks are well known. Inserting the symbolic names for the items is much faster if the names are simple. In your case it would be best to copy and paste them from the math formulas to get them drawn exactly in the same way. The math expression in the image has no connection with your example, it's copied and pasted from a PDF where formulas seemed to have same looking letters.

**ADD**
There's a comment which asks how to make 3 parallel curves. It was originally a single curve, the middle one. Duplicate it, change a wider stroke, convert the stroke to path (=Path > Stroke to Path) to get the outline, remove its fill, give a thin edge stroke, fix the top end by moving a couple of nodes with the node tool to the same places.

Path effect Pattern along a path may be also useful.

BTW. freeware MathMagic Lite can be used with Inkscape. You can save complex variable names and formulas as SVG file, several items in a single file, import it to Inkscape and move the items to their places in a drawing. Unfortunately copying and pasting directly is not reliable, but saving as SVG and importing is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: Doing this in solidworks is no harder than doing it in inkscape. You xan sketch 2D images in 3D applications.

Comment: I'm afraid the hard part is to purchase Solidworks.

Comment: thank you , can you briefly tell me how to draw 3 curved line in parallel ?

Comment: @user170412 It's inserted to the answer.